# Grouping and Sorting in RadGid

Tags: sorting, grouping, radgrid

I have a issue need to resolve.

How to group Data on Radgrid but no sort. Radgri only group, no sort. Because if Radgrid sort , data will incorrect

Please help me to resolve it

Thank all so much

Answer (score 1):

Set the `allowsorting` property to false.

```
<telerik:radgrid id="RadGrid1" runat="server" allowsorting="False">
```

Also, if you need to know how to group data, use a `GridCalculatedColumn`:

```
<telerik:GridCalculatedColumn UniqueName="Name" HeaderText="Name"
    DataFields="FirstName, LastName"
    Expression="{0} + ' ' + {1}">
</telerik:GridCalculatedColumn>
```